# Quick way to tell if current time is within 6 hours of midnight using JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

So I'm using JodaTime in an app I've got and I need a way to tell if the current time is within 6 hours of midnight. Well actually I need to know if the time is within 8 hours of 2am, but JodaTime seems to provide a constant for midnight so I was looking at that. Anyway, I've tried a number of different things but nothing quite works. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished simply by using JodaTime without any math involved.

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);

Period period = new Period(time, time.plusDays(1).toDateMidnight());
System.out.println(period.getHours());
```

The time.plusDays(1).toDateMidnight() (yes, I was lazy), is so that I'm comparing with the next midnight, and not with today's midnight (which already passed).

If you want to check both before and after, just check both periods.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a DateTime object.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
int i = getSecondOfDay();
```

Then using a little math we can find the number of seconds 6pm would be.
18hours*60min*60seconds= 64800 seconds.

```
if ( i > 64800 ){
   // Do what you need here 
}
```

I assumed you needed to tell if it was 8 hours of am of this current day and not a specific day.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hardcoded and pcalcao's answer is probably more flexible:

```
private static boolean isLessThan8HoursFrom2AM(DateTime date) {
    return (date.getHourOfDay() >= 18 || date.getHourOfDay() < 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if the time of day is 6 hours from midday.

```
if(Math.abs(timeOfDay - 43200) >= 21600) // first or last 6 hours of day.
```